# httpd folder is not there

Tags: https, ubuntu-14.04, httpd.conf, apache2.4

my apache web server httpd service is not available.
when I run command sudo service httpd status it gives an error **service not available**.

there is no httpd folder in /etc folder and no httpd.conf file in apache 2 
how can I add those files and folders

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu doesn't call the binary or service "httpd". It's called "apache2" there, for various reasons. This should be quite clear searching your package repository, google, etc.